# gnome desktop is making automatic annoying pronunciation sounds?

Tags: centos, gnome

for example when i put my mouse pointer to applications.It says "**windows applications label**" when i go to **network mangager -> wifi** it spells the words on each and every setting where my mouse goes.

How do i stop this?

Comment: It sounds like some accessibility setting, so look for those.

Comment: right there is somthing called `speech-dispatcher` was turned on by mistake